Flutter Get.to Navigation Not Updating ChattingView with New User Data
I'm using the Get package in Flutter for navigation in my chat application. I have a ChattingView that opens when a user taps on a conversation. However, navigating to a new ChattingView with a different user does not update the view; it reuses the existing instance.
Problem Description
User is in ChattingView with user: 1 and receives a chat message from user: 2.
Tapping on the push notification should open a new ChattingView with user: 2.
Instead, it reopens the ChattingView with user: 1.
Get.toNamed('/chatting', arguments: { 'user': user, });

class ChattingView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChattingViewState createState() => _ChattingViewState();
}

class _ChattingViewState extends State<ChattingView> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  late ChattingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final arguments = Get.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    _controller = Get.put(ChattingController(
      user: arguments['user'],
    ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

How can I ensure that each instance of ChattingView is unique and correctly shows the data for the new user when navigating from a notification?
Steps Taken:
Using Unique Keys: Tried using UniqueKey() for each instance.
Named Routes: Configured named routes and passed arguments.
Controller Initialization: Ensured the controller is initialized with the correct arguments.
Please help me resolve this issue. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
